# Excel.Binding class delete() method not actually deleting the binding

Tags: excel, office-js, scriptlab

I'm currently working on an Excel Add-in.

I have been trying for hours to add/remove bindings in Excel Online. I'm attaching an handler to each binding. If I add, delete() and then add again a binding for a given range (e.g: A1:A100), the event handler is called twice.

I made a gist with Script Lab to reproduce my code : https://gist.github.com/pasdechancee/b945008386804b426a127a0125d5b3ec

Here's the javascript code from the gist :

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {
  await removeListeners()
  await registerListeners()
  await removeListeners()
  await registerListeners()
  // Expected outcome : when we change a value in A1:A100, an event
  // is fired only ONCE (since the first listeners was removed) instead of twice
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}

async function listenersCallback({binding}){
  console.log(binding.id + " event")
}

/* delete all bindings */
function removeListeners() {
  return Excel.run(async context => {
    const bindings = context.workbook.bindings.load("items");
    await context.sync();
    for (let i = 0; i < bindings.items.length; i++) {
      bindings.items[i].delete();
    }
    await context.sync();
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}

/* register my binding */
function registerListeners() {
  return Excel.run(async context => {
    const newBinding = context.workbook.bindings.add(
        "A1:A100",
        "Range",
      "cc1c.onDataChangedBinding:" + "A1:A100"
      );
    newBinding.onDataChanged.add(listenersCallback);
    await context.sync();
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

For some reason, if I make the binding id unique, the eventListener is only called once so this could be a workaround... but I'd still like to make this right.

I'm new to Office-js so I might have screwed up with the context.sync() calls or something ?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated !! :)

Comment: The [help for the binding object in the Common Office APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.binding?view=excel-js-preview#id) says the id has to be unique in the document. I suspect that the same is true of the [Excel.Binding.id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.binding?view=excel-js-preview#id), even though the documentation does not say so. I'll see if I can find out from the Excel development team.

Comment: The Excel engineers have reproduced this. It is a bug and we are now tracking it. There's no ETA for a fix. FYI, Excel.Binding.id does NOT have to be unique, although you may need to make it unique as part of your workaround.

Comment: Hello Rick, thank you so much for such a fast support ! 
For now, I'll stick to my workaround, which works fine (making the id unique). I just hope that the performance impact remains negligible.